# New to Java, need help on storing elements from textfields into custom type object and storing the object into an ArrayList

Tags: java

I need help on how to store user string input from the textfields into the `Appointment`) inside an `ArrayList`. The error I'm getting is 'cannot convert string to object `Appointment`', I can't figure out how to store both the time and appointment into the custom type object and then storing it into the `ArrayList`.

I'm attempting this within my `ButtonListener` method

```
class appointment{

    private String time;
    private String appt;

    public appointment()
    {
        time = " ";
        appt = " ";
    }

    public appointment(String time, String appt)
    {
        this.time = time;
        this.appt = appt;
    }

    public String getTime()
    {
        return this.time;
    }

    public String getAppt()
    {
        return this.appt;
    }

    public void setTime(String time1)
    {
        time1 = time;
    }

    public void setAppt(String appt1)
    {
        appt1 = appt;
    }
}

    private class ButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>

    {
        private Button pressedButton = new Button();
        List<appointment> str = new ArrayList<appointment>();

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() instanceof Button)
            {
                pressedButton = (Button) e.getSource();

                if(pressedButton == submit)
                {
                    appointment i = time1.getText();
                    appointment g = appt1.getText();
                    str.add(i, g);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the Appointment object and put the values to the constructor then add the object to 
the ArrayList, like this:

```
if(pressedButton == submit) {
    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(time1.getText(), appt1.getText());
    str.add(appointment);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added");
}
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash No, I didn't make any down vote for anyone. For the first one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718846/find-the-longest-and-shortest-words-in-a-text-file-using-methods/61718920 Also I get downvote and I deleted my answer. For the second answer I didn't participate in it: stackoverflow.com/a/61736516/10819573

Comment: I just focus on my answer, not the other's answers. I faced the same situation lots and I guess the reason the experienced users in this community

Comment: Thanks, @sc0der for the response. I appreciate your good spirit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new Appointment object and then insert into **str**.

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(time1.getText(), appt1.getText());
str.add(appointment);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an ArrayList of Appointment objects and you're trying to give it a couple of time and string , what you will have to do is to create a new instance of Appointment and add it to the list , like this :

```
String time = time1.getText();
String appt = appt1.getText();
Appointment app = new Appointment(time,appt);
str.add(app);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. Is there a way I can print out the objects in the ArrayList so that I can test the inputs are all being stored

Comment: @Elk yes , you can use a method toString() , in your Appointment class , it gonna make you print the instance showing time and appt , you can do it in this way ===== public String toString() { return this.getTime() + " " + this.getAppt() ; } ====== and then you can print the content of your arraylist like this ====== for ( Appointement a : app ) { System.out.println ( a ) ; } ======